# Resharper 16.3 testrunner does not support appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core, resharper

Since testrunner in Resharper now supports .Net core then I want to switch, but a piece of code does not work for my integration tests.

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
```

I just want to read an entry in my appsettings.json file.

Is it a leftover that this part does not work, and exactly what would the correct approach be to solve this? (I would prefer not to have the absolute path, and have something that works both for test and production code.)

Comment: If that code is executed in your test project but your appsettings.json is in your web project, its obvious why it's not working. Also the appsettings.json is not a source file, so you'd need to copy it over to the executable file via buildOptions > copyToOutput option in project.json. You'll have to provide more information about your exact project structure. Of course you can also use relative path: `.SetBasePath("../MyProjectUnderTest/appsettings.json")`

Comment: My test project have an appsettings file, and the library I hit does not have an appsettings file. When I run the integration test from Visual Studio test runner then everything works like expect, even though it is code in my library that has the Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() call

Comment: Odd setup. Why would you do something like this? Sounds like a design issue to me, as I can't think of any reason why the class library should access the appsettings.json (especially since its name is arbitrary and not fixed like web.config). When you create a netstandard library you should use the options pattern to pass options to your services and have an registration method (for IServiceCollection) which takes a `IConfiguration` or `IConfigurationRoot` as parameter to read out the settings from a given file

Comment: ReSharper gives: "<project>\\bin\\Debug\\netcoreapp1.0" Visual Studio gives: <project>. I am also certain that normal resharper test runner (before .net core) could handle this. But I agree that it is a fairly bad setup. I just find it wierd that it doesn't work.

Comment: This might be related to a ReSharper issue where the current directory for .net core testing is incorrect when compared against `dotnet test`. See [RSRP-462088](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-462088)